# Strange behavior of isset

Tags: php, php-5.3

isset() in php 5.3 seems to be behaving unexpectedly. I have a class called DB details that encapsulates a bunch of string properties with getters and setters.

$dbdetails->getDatabasename() evaluates to a string ("mydb")

**This throws a 500 error:**

```
if(!isset($dbdetails->getDatabasename())){
//do something
}
```

**This works fine**

```
$databasename = $dbdetails->getDatabasename();
if(!isset($databasename)){
//do something
}
```

I wasn't able to see any log output because apache sent back a 500 even though the error ini param is set (sic) to On. I know this is something to do with the isset call for sure.
Any idea what could be wrong, or did I find a PHP bug?

Comment: Which error ini param is set to on? `display_errors`? - for some errors your need `error_log`  as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `isset` function checks whether a variable is set. Checking against `$databasename` is valid, because it is a variable that can be set or not. Checking against a function is invalid, because it simply isn't a variable.

You probably want to use `is_null( $value )` when checking the immediate result of a function.

---

An example from the comments on the the [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) documentation:

```
<?php
function test( ) { return null; }
var_dump( is_null( test( ) ) ); // displays "true"
var_dump( isset( test( ) ) ); // parse error, because "test()" is not a variable
?>
```

- [PHP: is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)
- [PHP: isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @programmerravi You're welcome :) Don't forget to flag either answer as 'accepted' when you are content.

Answer (score 4):

That's how [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) works. Same as [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty). They can only work with a variable, not an expression. From [the documentation](http://php.net/isset#refsect1-function.isset-notes):

> `isset()` only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the `defined()` function.

Therefore, `isset(function_call())` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Excellent -- guess this is another one of those 'This ain't Java, noob' things! Thank you

Comment: The PHP developers actually put out an RFC for exactly this change about a month ago. Although from the looks of it, empty() will be getting this behavior but not isset() https://wiki.php.net/rfc/empty_isset_exprs